# Get sinewave display from audio file

Tags: ios, swift, audio, signal-processing

What is the best approach to convert an audio file into a simple sine wave to show pitch, using Swift?

I'm asking because many online docs seem outdated.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean actual pitch recognition, or just some pretty waveform graphics to show the user?

Comment: What docs have you looked at? From what you said, it sounds like you want break the audio-wave into its sinusoidal components using an FFT...is this correct?

Comment: @Linuxios actually recognize the tone (low = dip in graph; high = up)

Comment: @narner I've tried looking at a few, but this one looks the most up to date: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2014/10/sound-synthesis-in-swift-core-audio.html However, I'm trying to GET the graph FROM the audio. This tutorial creates the audio. I've also tried converting this java app: https://github.com/drshriveer/sinewave

Comment: As @narner said, you'll need to break the audio into sinusoidals using a Fourier Transform. There's a great conceptual explanation of that [here](http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/). From there you can see how you have to get the audio as linear PCM, and compute the FFT of that, probably using the Accelerate library.

Comment: Also there's a difference between the sine wave that *is* the sound, and a wave indicating pitch. If you want a wave indicating pitch, you'll have to extract pitch data from the sine waves that the Fourier Transform gives you (frequency of the wave, convert to Hertz, use that.)

Comment: @linuxios thanks for the explanation. Based on your explanation, I'm trying to obtain the wave indicating pitch. I'm still not sure how to compute the FFT using swift.

Comment: @Emma: mattt has a interface to the Accelerate library for Swift called [Surge](https://github.com/mattt/Surge). It's got an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) function.

Comment: @Emma: Worth mentioning that you should really google a tutorial on pitch recognition in any language now that you have the library itself, I've actually never done this stuff.

Comment: @Linuxios Thank you for finding an interface to the Accelerate lib. If I understand this correctly, I need to: 1) break audio into sine waves using FT, 2) extract the pitch data (get frequency and convert to hertz), 3) convert audio to linear PCM, 4) compute the FFT of the linear PCM -- this is certainly more complex than I originally thought

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73280/discussion-between-linuxios-and-emma).

Comment: A sine wave does **NOT** show pitch.  Pitch is something different (and more complex than you originally thought).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want actual code, or general concepts. I can give the latter.

When you read the audio data in a mono file, each audio sample data point is a value you would plot on the Y axis. For CD audio these values would range from -32768 to 32767. So in psuedo-code:

```
int samples[NUM_SAMPLES]; // assume this has your data
moveTo(0, samples[0])
for (i = 1; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++) {
  lineTo(i, samples[i]);
}
```

If you want to horizontally zoom the waveform display the code is quite bit more subtle.